# Zxing compiles for device fine, but fails in simulator

Tags: ios, zxing

I have downloaded the latest zxing library via SVN, then integrated according to README file. I was able to integrate, compile and test on device. However, when compiling in the simulator I get:

```
Missing required architecture i386 in file
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZXingWidgetController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-ZXingWidgetController in ScannerViewController.o
```

and

```
 error: 'AVCaptureDevice' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I have attempted to "weak" link (optional in Xcode 4) the AVFoundation library to fix the second error but no dice.

Anyone know why this would occur? A search seems to pull up the opposite problem, failing on device but succeeding in simulator. Very weird.

Edit:

One more thing I forgot to mention is I have tried to delete the build folders and simulator, then trying to rebuild. Same errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting this project to update for iOS5, the following solution fixed this.

Swap out the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 for the ZXing.xcodeproj.